# insert data from html table to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

First I convert CSV to html table, next I post data from form html table to this below script and then INSERT new records to database:

```
foreach($file_data as $row)
 {
  $data[] = '("'.$row[$_POST["sku"]].'", "'.$row[$_POST["stock"]].'")';
 }

 if(isset($data))
 {
  $query = "
  INSERT INTO products 
  (sku, stock) 
  VALUES ".implode(",", $data)."
  ";
```

This above function working correct and I can insert example 1000 records to data mysql.

And now I need change this function and UPDATE mysql table.

I try some like this:

```
 $file_data = $_SESSION['file_data'];

 unset($_SESSION['file_data']);

 foreach($file_data as $row)
 {
  $data[] = '("'.$row[$_POST["sku"]].'")';
  $title[] = '("'.$row[$_POST["title"]].'")';
  $lang_id[] = '("'.$row[$_POST["lang_id"]].'")';
 }

 if(isset($data))
 {
  $query = "
  UPDATE product_details
  SET title = ".implode(",", $title)." 
  WHERE sku = ".implode(",", $data)." AND lang_id = ".implode(",", $lang_id)."
  ";

  $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

  if($statement->execute())
  {
   echo 'Data Imported Successfully';
  }
 }
```

and this update function working, but only when is available/post 1 record in CSV file (html table). When I try update/post example 2 or more records from html table (csv file) then not working.

I know currently from this above function I get result when I post only 1 record:

```
UPDATE product_details
SET title = title1 WHERE sku = "P6951H0E3-Q12"  AND lang_id = 1;
```

Then this above query working. But When I try post 2 or more records then I get output query somelike this:

```
UPDATE product_details
    SET title = title1 WHERE sku = "P6951H0E3-Q12"  AND lang_id = 1
    SET title = title2 WHERE sku = "PLD_4051/S";" AND lang_id = 1
```

and this  above SQL query  never will   work but how to get result  like this:

```
UPDATE product_details SET title = "title1" WHERE sku = "P6951H0E3-Q12" AND lang_id = "1"; 
UPDATE product_details SET title = "title2" WHERE sku = "PLD_4051/S" AND lang_id = "1";
```

Comment: I don't think you can update multiple rows in the way that you are doing. Run the query for two rows in phpmyadmin and see if it works. If you send it two titles, two skus and two ids, are you expecting that it will "know" which title is intending for which sku/id combination?

Comment: You need to use Prepared Statements here (well, almost everywhere, including in your insert query) - you could prepare the query before looping around the title, sku and lang_id arrays and provide the array elements as parameters inside the loop.

Comment: Move the IF statement in side loop it will work;

Comment: I understand currently I get result some like this " UPDATE products
  SET stock = 115
  WHERE sku = "P6951H0E3-Q12"
  SET stock = 225
  WHERE sku = "PLD_4051/S";"   but I need get:  UPDATE products SET stock = 115 WHERE sku = "P6951H0E3-Q12";
UPDATE products SET stock = 225 WHERE sku = "PLD_4051/S";

Comment: @Mehrwarz thank you for your Tip.   Could you give a hint as in answear to what it should look like in side loop if statement ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this will work

```
$file_data = $_SESSION['file_data'];

unset($_SESSION['file_data']);

foreach ($file_data as $row) {
    $data = $row[$_POST["sku"]];
    $title = $row[$_POST["title"]];
    $lang_id = $row[$_POST["lang_id"]];

    if (isset($data)) {
        $statement = $connect->prepare("UPDATE product_details  SET title = '$title'
        WHERE sku = '$data' AND lang_id = '$lang_id'");

        if (!$statement->execute()) {
            $error = 'None or part of the data was updated';
        }
    }
}
echo $error ?? 'Data Updated Successfully';
```

Comment: Currently I get output: "Notice: Array to string conversion in import_update_title_csv.php on line 21

Notice: Array to string conversion in import_update_title_csv.php on line 22

Notice: Array to string conversion in import_update_title_csv.php on line 22

Notice: Array to string conversion in import_update_title_csv.php on line 21

Notice: Array to string conversion in import_update_title_csv.php on line 22

Notice: Array to string conversion in import_update_title_csv.php on line 22
Data Updated Successfully"

Comment: But I check in database and records still not update

Comment: and in line 21 and 22 I've:   LINE21$statement = $connect->prepare("UPDATE product_details  SET title = '$title'    LINE22WHERE sku = '$data' AND lang_id = '$lang_id'");

Comment: My bad. no need to have $data as array. let me edit my code and change $data[] to $data.

Comment: Yes, lines CSV https://prnt.sc/A5ISregFc8U4  and table html mapping  https://prnt.sc/L842IpjVhE5E

Comment: ....change $data[] to $data.   yes! this is corect. Working amazing! Thank you