# How to load data to multiple tables SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my script for import data to mysql:

```
foreach ($file_data as $row) {
    
    $sku = $row[$_POST["sku"]];
    $title = $row[$_POST["title"]];
    $slug = $row[$_POST["title"]];
    $product_type = "physical";
    $description = $row[$_POST["description"]];
}
   if(isset($sku))
 {
  $query = "
  INSERT INTO products
  (sku, slug, product_type) 
  VALUES ".implode(",", $sku).",".implode(",", $slug).",".implode(",", $product_type)."
  ";

  $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

  if($statement->execute())
  {
   echo 'Data Imported Successfully';
  }
 }
```

And now can anyone help me how to now load `$title` and `$description` to second table `product_details` ?

@update  @Mehrwarz

```
foreach ($file_data as $row) {
    
    $sku = $row[$_POST["sku"]];
    $title = $row[$_POST["title"]];
    $slug = $row[$_POST["slug"]];
    $product_type = "physical";
    $description = $row[$_POST["description"]];
    
 if (isset($sku)) {
        $statement = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO products
         (sku, slug, product_type) 
         VALUES '$sku','$slug','$product_type'");
       $statement2 = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO product_details
         (title, description) 
         VALUES '$title','$description'");
   
   
        if (!$statement->execute()) {
            $error = 'None or part of the data was updated';
        }
    }
}
echo $error ?? 'Data Updated Successfully';
```

Comment: Well you already know how to make an insert. So what exactly is the problem? Are you, by any chance, asking how to get the ID of the row inserted into products, so you can reference it in the product details table? If not then it's unclear where the issue is.

Comment: @ADyson currently in this query I can load data only to one table "products" and now how to add in the same time and load data to second table "product_details" ?

Comment: To insert to another table you just make another insert query

Comment: Your question is already answered in the you previous question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74576424/insert-data-from-html-table-to-mysql/74576695?noredirect=1#comment131640671_74576695

Comment: @Mehrwarz yes I think now about this. And do  you think in this answear this should work? $statement = $connect->prepare("UPDATE products SET sku = '$sku'
        WHERE sku = '$data' AND lang_id = '$lang_id'");    $statement2 = $connect->prepare("UPDATE product_details  SET title = '$title'
        WHERE sku = '$data' AND lang_id = '$lang_id'");  ? (please don't look at the variables, just wondering if adding statment2 and another query will solve the problem.)

Comment: @Mehrwarz you mean somelike this ? https://prnt.sc/CDLu92ZbUgeh

Comment: First loop through each row and create a values tring like ('row1val1','row1val2','row1Val3'),('row2val1','row2val2','row2val3').... for both tables and then run the insert query.

Comment: @Mehrwarz currenly I add loop through each row , but im not sure with this  ('row1val1','row1val2','row1Val3'),('row2val1','row2val2','row2val3'). Can you please check my update and help me correct this code in answear?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [insert data from html table to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74576424/insert-data-from-html-table-to-mysql)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This may work for you.

```
$T1Values = "";
$T2Values = "";

foreach ($file_data as $row) {
    $T1Values .= "('" . $row[$_POST['sku']] . "','" . $row[$_POST['slug']] . ",'" . $row[$_POST['product_type']] . "),";
    $T2Values .= "('" . $row[$_POST['title']] . "','" . $row[$_POST['description']] . "'),";
}
if (isset($sku)) {

    $T1Values = trim(',', $T1Values);
    $T2Values = trim(',', $T2Values);

    $query1 = "INSERT INTO products (sku, slug, product_type) VALUES($T1Values)";

    $statement = $connect->prepare($query1);

    if ($statement->execute()) {
        $query2 = "INSERT INTO product_details (title, product_details) VALUES($T2Values)";
        $statement = $connect->prepare($query2);
        if ($statement->execute()) {
            echo "All records inserted successfully";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to sql injection. There's no point using prepared statements unless you also parameterise the input values.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can push any array

```
<?php

$query_array = [];



foreach ($file_data as $row) {
    
    $sku = $row[$_POST["sku"]];
    $title = $row[$_POST["title"]];
    $slug = $row[$_POST["title"]];
    $product_type = "physical";
    $description = $row[$_POST["description"]];

    if(isset($sku)){

        $query = 'INSERT INTO products
        (sku, slug, product_type) 
        VALUES SET title="'.$title.',sku="'.$sku.'", etc.. #add more"';

        $query = rtrim($query,',');
        array_push($query_array,$query);

    }




}

foreach ($query_array as $key => $value) {
    $mysqlconn->query($value);
}
```

Comment: and how to now add to this  to insert data $title = $row[$_POST["title"]];  and $description = $row[$_POST["description"]]; to second table product_details ?